# Showing that a given function satisfies certain properties. Related to Lebesgue integral, limits and supremums.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral, supremum-and-infimum

For any integrable function $f$, consider the following properties:

$$ \underline{V_0 \text{ property:}} \, \, \lim_{r \to 0} \, \sup_{x \in \Bbb R^n} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|^p \, dy = 0;$$

$$ \underline{V_\infty \text{ property:}} \, \, \lim_{r \to \infty} \, \sup_{x \in \Bbb R^n} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)|^p \, dy = 0,$$

where $0 < \lambda < n$ and $1 \leqslant p < \infty$ are fixed elements. My goal is to show that the function

$$ f_\epsilon(x) = \begin{cases} |x|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p} + \epsilon} \quad \text{ if } |x| \leqslant 1 \\ |x|^{\frac{\lambda-n}{p}} \quad \, \, \, \, \text{ if } |x| \geqslant 1 \end{cases},$$
where $\epsilon > 0$, has $V_0$ property but doesn't have $V_\infty$ property. Usually, when I encounter this kind of functions, my intuition is to check whether I am dealing with a radially decreasing function, since this allows me to ignore $\sup_{x \in \Bbb R^n},$ allowing me to deal with the problem using only the integral over $B(0,r).$ In this case, I am quite sure that the function in question isn't radially decreasing and thus this strategy can't be applied. The only other thing that came to my mind is to deal with the integral over $B(x,r)$ directly, which lead me to

$$ \int_{B(x,r)} |f_\epsilon(y)|^p \, dy = \int_{B(x,r)} |y|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p} + \epsilon} \, \chi_{B(0,1)}(y) \, dy + \int_{B(x,r)} |y|^{\frac{\lambda-n}{p}} \, \chi_{\Bbb R^n \setminus B(0,1)}(y) \, dy$$

which equals

$$ \int_{B(x,r) \cap B(0,1)} |y|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p} + \epsilon} \, dy + \int_{B(x,r) \setminus B(0,1)}  |y|^{\frac{\lambda-n}{p}} \, dy.$$

But after this I am unable to proceed. I don't think my new strategy is really usefull, so I am mainly looking for where to start. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: $f_\epsilon$ is radial symmetric, so you can use the transformation formula to integrate over a sphere with varying radius instead of the ball.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more @stange ? I am not familiar with the idea you stated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the coarea formula, we find that
\begin{align*}
\int_{B(x,r)} \vert f_\epsilon \vert^p\,dy &= \int_0^r\int_{\partial B(x,s)} \vert f_\epsilon \vert^p \,d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}ds \\
&=\int_0^r \int_{\partial B(x,s)} \vert y \vert^{\lambda - n + p\epsilon} \mathbf{1}_{B(0,1)}(y) + \vert y \vert^{\lambda - n}\mathbf{1}_{B(0,1)^c}(y)\,d\mathcal{H}^{n-1}ds \\
&= \int_0^r \underbrace{\mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial B(x,s))}_{ = c s^{n-1}}\Big( \vert s \vert^{\lambda - n + p\epsilon}\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(s) + \vert s \vert^{\lambda - n}\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)^c}(s)\Big)ds \\
&= c\int_0^r s^{\lambda - 1 + p\epsilon}\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(s) + s^{\lambda - 1}\mathbf{1}_{(0,1)^c}(s)ds.
\end{align*}
Now, to prove that $V_0$ is satisfied, consider $r\in(0,1)$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then
$$ r^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x,r)} \vert f_\epsilon\vert^p\,dy = cr^{-\lambda} \int_0^r s^{\lambda - 1 + p\epsilon}\,ds = c\frac{r^{p\epsilon}}{\lambda + p\epsilon} \rightarrow 0 $$
as $r\rightarrow\infty$. To prove that $V_\infty$ is not satisfied, let $r\in (1,\infty)$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be arbitrary. Then
\begin{align*}
r^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x,r)} \vert f_\epsilon\vert^p\,dy &= cr^{-\lambda} \int_0^1 s^{\lambda - 1 + p\epsilon}\,ds + cr^{-\lambda}\int_0^r s^{\lambda - 1}\,ds \\
&= \frac{c}{r^{\lambda}(\lambda + p\epsilon)} + \frac{c}{\lambda} \rightarrow \frac{c}{\lambda}
\end{align*}
as $r\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is one detail that is confusing me: at one point, we're dealing with the integral $$ c\int_0^r s^{\lambda - 1 + p\epsilon} \mathbf{1}_{B(0,1)} + s^{\lambda - 1} \mathbf{1}_{B(0,1)^c} \, ds. $$ I understand the calculations you made in the next step, but I don't see how the characteristic function is unchanged through this calculations. Can you perhaps elaborate a bit more on this part?

Comment: Well, the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_{B(0,1)}$ (and $\mathbf{1}_{B(0,1)^c}$) depend on $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, which is arbitrary, and has no influence on these calculations. Edit: I changed now the integration variable from $x$ to $y$, maybe that was a bit confusing too.

Comment: I think I am really missing something now. Initially, I believe that you made the decomposition  $|f_\epsilon(y)| = f_\epsilon(y) = |y|^{\lambda - n + p\epsilon}\mathbf{1}_{B(0,1)}(y) + |y|^{\lambda - n} \mathbf{1}_{B(0,1)^c}(y).$ With this, the characteristic function depend on $y$. Thus, after you make all the changes you made, shouldn't the characteristic function depend on $s$ ? In other words, at one point we shoulve have the integral $$ c\int_{0}^r s^{\lambda -1 + p\epsilon} \mathbf{1}_{B(0,1)}(s) + s^{\lambda - 1} \mathbf{1}_{B(0,1)^c} (s) \, ds,$$  correct?

Comment: @xyz You're completely right. I edited by answer now and completed it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I agree with everything now.