# How to prove that ${\displaystyle \, \, \lim_{r \to 0} \, \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n} \, r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f_\alpha(y)|^p \, dy = 0}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, lebesgue-integral, supremum-and-infimum

Let $1 \leqslant p < \infty$ and $0 < \lambda < n$. Consider the function $f_\alpha \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ defined by

$$ f_\alpha(x) := \|x\|^{\frac{\lambda - n + \alpha}{p}} \chi_{B(0,1)}(x) + \| x \|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}} \chi_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B(0,1)}(x), \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R^n, $$

where $\alpha > 0$ is an arbitrarily fixed constant. My goal is to show that $f_\alpha$ satisfies the following property:

$$ \lim_{r \to 0} \, \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n} \, r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f_\alpha(y)|^p \, dy = 0. $$

**My attempt.** Let $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $0 < r < 1/3$ be arbitrary elements. In order to prove what I want I decided to split in the following cases: $(i) \, \| x \| < 2r $ and $(ii) \, \| x \| \geqslant 2r.$

For case $(i)$, It is obvious that $B(x,r) \subset B(0,3r) \subset B(0,1)$, which implies that

$$ r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f_\alpha(y)|^p \, dy \leqslant r^{-\lambda}\int_{B(0,3r)} |f_\alpha(y)|^p \, dy = r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(0,3r)} \| y \|^{\lambda - n + \alpha} \, dy.  $$

Hence, passing to polar coordinates, we obtain

$$ r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(0,3r)} \| y \|^{\lambda - n + \alpha} \, dy = c(n) r^{-\lambda} \int_0^{3r} t^{\lambda - n + \alpha + n -1} \, dt = c(n)r^{-\lambda} \int_0^{3r} t^{\lambda + \alpha - 1 } \, dt = c(n) \frac{3^{\lambda + \alpha}}{\lambda + \alpha} r^\alpha.  $$

This is obviously a good upper bound since $r^\alpha \to 0$ as $r \to 0$.

Now I should find a similar bound for the case $ \| x \| \geqslant 2r$ but this is where I am stuck.

**Remark.** I have already asked a similar question to this one in MSE ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4836036/showing-that-a-given-function-satisfies-certain-properties-related-to-lebesgue)). The answer provided there uses complex results that I would like to avoid applying, since I believe this can be solved with less machinery.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Try and find a good bound for $|y|$ in terms of $r$ when $||x||\geq 2r$. You can assume $||x||<2/3$ so only the $B(0,1)$ term is left, the case $||x||\geq 2/3$ should be simple.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @WillowWisp . I have been trying to find a "good bound" for $\| y \|$ in terms of $r$ when $ \| x \| \geqslant 2r$. I have been able to do the following: for any $y \in B(x,r)$, we have that $$ 2r \leqslant \| x \| \leqslant \| x - y \| + \| y \| < r + \| y \| \implies r < \| y \|. $$ Is this the bound you had in mind? (Here, I haven't assumed that $ \| x \| < 2/3$).

Comment: Yes, that's what I had in mind! The 2/3 thing was moreso when applying it to bound $|f_\alpha(y)|$ whenever $\lambda-n+\alpha<0$.

Comment: @WillowWisp So, without considering the assumption $\| x \| < 2/3$ that seems to be just technical, the bound above implies that $B(x,r) \subset \mathbb R^n \setminus B(0,r)$. Hence, it follows that $$ r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f_\alpha(y)|^p \, dy \leqslant r^{-\lambda} \int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B(0,r)} |f_\alpha(y)|^p \, dy.$$ Moreover, splitting the latter integral we obtain $$ \int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B(0,r)} |f_\alpha(y)|^p \, dy = \int_{B(0,1) \setminus B(0,r)} \| y \|^{\lambda - n + \alpha} \, dy + \int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B(0,1)} \| y \|^{\lambda - n} \, dy.$$

Comment: @WillowWisp Passing to polar coordinates, we obtain $$ \int_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B(0,r)} |f_\alpha(y)|^p \, dy = c(n) \left( \int_r^1 t^{\lambda + \alpha - 1} \, dt + \int_{1}^\infty t^{\lambda - 1} \, dt \right) $$ but the latter integral doesn't seem to converge. Did you have an alternative approach in mind?

Comment: There's actually a simpler way that doesn't involve polar coordinates. Instead of bounding the domain of integration, keep the domain the same and try bounding $|f_\alpha(y)|^p$ directly by $r$ (assuming we have $B(x,r) \subset B(0,1)$, but as you said that's just technical so the arguments are easier to write).

Comment: @WillowWisp Ok, so assuming that $B(x,r) \subset B(0,1)$ I get the bound $$ r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f_\alpha(y)|^p \, dy = r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} \| y \|^{\lambda - n + \alpha} \, dy < r^{-\lambda} r^{\lambda - n + \alpha} |B(x,r)| = r^{\alpha} |B(0,1)|, $$ under the extra assumption that $\lambda - n + \alpha < 0$, which is a good bound with this extra assumption. Do you know how I can get rid of this assumption?

Comment: Exactly! And in the case $\lambda-n+\alpha\geq 0$, it might help to realize that the singularity at $0$ is gone, and $f_\alpha$ is actually globally bounded.

Comment: @WillowWisp Basically for the assumptions $B(x,r) \subset B(0,1)$ and $\lambda - n + \alpha \geqslant 0$ we get that $\| y \| < 1 $ for every $y \in B(x,r)$, so that $\| y \|^{\lambda -n + \alpha} \leqslant 1$ for every $y \in B(x,r)$. Hence, under these assumptions we get the bound $$ r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f_\alpha(y)|^p \, dy = r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} \| y \|^{\lambda - n + \alpha} \, dy \leqslant r^{-\lambda} |B(x,r)| = r^{n-\lambda} w_n, $$ which again is a good bound since $n > \lambda$. Is this what you meant for this case?

Comment: Yep, that's it! And we get $B(x,r) \subset B(0,1)$ from the assumption $||x||<2/3$, but the case $||x||\geq 2/3$ can be treated similarly as what you just did, since we can also bound $|f_\alpha(y)|$ globally on $B(x,r)$.

Comment: @WillowWisp Thank you for your help. I believe I was able to solve it with your hints :) !