# How to prove that $ {\displaystyle \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n, \, r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f_\alpha(y)|^p \, dy < \infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, supremum-and-infimum

Let $1 \leqslant p < \infty$ and $0 < \lambda < n$. Consider the function $f_\alpha \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ defined by

$$ f_\alpha(x) := \|x\|^{\frac{\lambda - n + \alpha}{p}} \chi_{B(0,1)}(x) + \| x \|^{\frac{\lambda - n}{p}} \chi_{\mathbb R^n \setminus B(0,1)}(x), \quad \forall x \in \mathbb R^n, $$

where $\alpha > 0$ is an arbitrarily fixed constant. My goal is to show that $f_\alpha$ satisfies the following property:

$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n, \, r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)} |f_\alpha(y)|^p \, dy < \infty. $$

**My attempt.** I wasn't able to make any usefull progress but I believe I should start by analysing different cases. For context, yesterday I posted a question about this same function but proving another (similar) property ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4887290/how-to-prove-that-displaystyle-lim-r-to-0-sup-x-in-mathbb-r)) and there I had to consider the cases $(i) \| x \| < 2r$ and $(ii) \| x \| \geqslant 2r$ to reach the result. Here we have two varying parameters so I believe the splitting is so easy to figure out.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: $f_\alpha(x)$ only depends on $\|x\|,$ and the only problem with estimates is near $0$ when $\lambda-n+\alpha<0,$ my intuition tells me.

Comment: It is not hard to see that: $$|f_\alpha(y)|^p=\|y\|^{\lambda-n+\alpha} \chi_{(0,1)}(\|y\|)+y^{\lambda-n}\chi_{[1,\infty)}(\|y\|).$$ $f$ is already non-negative, and since the two sets are disjoint, the power  can be applied to each set  seperately. This would not be true of the sets were not disjoint, but here they are.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for your observations. All that you wrote is correct and I am aware of these facts. Do you have any idea for the initial split?

Comment: If you are aware of these facts, tell us first in the question, rather than waiting for me to waste my time duplicating the effort.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude in my last comment. I appreciate every bit of help I get on MSE. Next time I will add more details to the post to be clear of what I am already aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Remark: I expect the ideas below work, although I did not check thoroughly the calculations, in particular, whether they are rigorous.*

For any $x\in\mathbb R^n$, $r>0$, and $y\in B(x,r)$, we have $|f_\alpha(y)|^p\le \|y\|^{\lambda-n}$.
So it suffices to show that
$$I=r^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x,r)} \|y\|^{\lambda-n} dy<\infty$$
To bound $I$ we consider two cases which you suggested.
Let $V_n$ be the volume of $B(0,1)$.

Suppose that $\|x\|\ge 2r$. Then $\|y\|\ge r$ for each $y\in B(x,r)$, so
$$I\le r^{-\lambda}\int_{B(x,r)} r^{\lambda-n} dy\le
r^{-\lambda}\cdot r^{\lambda-n}\cdot r^nV_n =V_n.$$

Suppose now that $\|x\|\le 2r$. Then $B(x,r)\subset B(0,3r)$, so
$$I\le r^{-\lambda}\int_{B(0,3r)} \|y\|^{\lambda-n} dy=
r^{-\lambda}\int_0^{3r} t^{\lambda-n} V_n nt^{n-1} dt=$$
$$nV_n r^{-\lambda}\int_0^{3r} t^{\lambda-1} dt=
nV_n r^{-\lambda}\frac {t^{\lambda}}{\lambda} {\Huge|}_0^{3r}=
nV_n r^{-\lambda}\frac {(3r)^\lambda}{\lambda} =
\frac {nV_n3^\lambda}{\lambda}.$$

Comment: Very good. Thanks.